# How to retrieve output SQL code from sublime editor

Tags: mysql, sql, editor, sublimetext3

I'm writing my SQL code on the sublime text editor. I have created a table, and I want to be able to see the output of my table. However, I do not know how to do this on the sublime text editor. Could someone help me out on this?

This is my code so far could you show my errors:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory(Monitor, Serial Number);

SELECT FROM * inventory
```

This should pretty much output out the columns, but I am not able to see that.

Comment: paste that code into where your you can run queries... like phpMyAdmin for example.

Comment: I think you actually need to use a database. Install mysql on your machine and run the scripts there

Comment: Also, you didn't use an insert statement, so your table would be empty

Comment: Be sure to check out the proper syntax for commands before using them. [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) has very specific requirements. Try and keep your table and column names all lower-case, and avoid putting spaces in column names. Nothing about this will work until you get the syntax right, it should be generating a bunch of errors.

Comment: if you just want to check and see if your queries run and don't have a mysql installed yet, you can test your queries on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: You should also use a tool like [MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org) to help build your tables and run queries.

Comment: And a good practice is to have an unique, autoincremented ID column on each table

Comment: @TinTran  CREATE TABLE celebs (id INTEGER, name TEXT, age INTEGER);
INSERT INTO celebs (id, name, age) VALUES (1, 'Justin Bieber', 21);
SELECT * FROM celebs;

Comment: i created that and put that on sqlfiddle.com, but i am not getting any output.. Could my code be wrongg?

Comment: so where is a link to your fiddle?

Comment: i solved the issue on sqlfiddle!